# JQuery percent loaded very slow in Firefox / Chrome - IE no issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress

I'm using http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/

All seems fine...

```
// initialise progress meter
initMeter('progressMeter',150);

function initMeter(id,size)
{
// initialise upload meter
uploader = $('#'+id).percentageLoader({width: size, height: size, controllable : false, progress : 0.5});
uploader.setProgress(0);
uploader.setValue('0'+sizeUnit);
}
```

When the meter loads in IE, I see the gauge image and the progress moving along with the percentage loaded and the amount of KB/MB processed no problems.

However, when viewing in FF/Chrome, I see the gauge image and the progress moving, but the centre percentage and the number of KB/MB uploaded takes a few seconds to show on large files, and for small files, it finishes uploading before the gauge information is even displayed?

Why is this happening?

Thanks,
1DMF

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was a timing issue, as I was calling AJAX to upload the FormData immediately after calling the initMeter function all from within the sendForm function

So I moved the initMeter call to the $(on.submit) of the form, which then calls the sendForm function which starts the AJAX upload and callback for progress, all seems to be working fine.